# How to check if list of field values exists in db mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to know if there is a way to find if the array of string values exists as individual field values in collections in mongodb?

For example I have the following schema

```
user:[{name:'abc',email:'email1'},{name:'efg',email:'email2'},{name:'hij',email:'email3'},{name:'zyx',email:'email4'}]
```

Now if I have an array of emails, say arr=['email1','email3']

Then I want to check if these emails of the array already exists as email value in the user schema. Is there a way I can do this with just one query? As right now I am iterating through the array and checking if emails exists one by one, but if array is too large it takes too much time.

**Note: I want to just check if all these emails in array exists in collection and not just one or two of the emails. All the emails in that array should be present, if anyone of the emails is not present I should get to know**

Like for example if i do the following

```
const data= db.users.checkAllEmails(array); // query function which needs to be implemented
```

and if I check `if(data.length===array.length)` then this should return true.

Comment: your expectation is not clear as per **if anyone of the emails is not present I should get to know**, can you show your expected result,

Comment: @turivishal I have updated the question, i hope it's clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$in`

```
db.collection.find({
  email: {
    $in: [
      "email3",
      "email4"
    ]
  }
})
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OhmRoqTcKti)**

Comment: Ok, sure, update the question and let me know

Comment: yeah ig $in works fine... I thought $in checks for one of the values to be present..